# CSS-Selector :child(> n)?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I got the problem that I got a variable amount of child-elements.
My :last-child :first-child rules should only apply, when there are at least 3 children

I tried :only-child, which can overwrite :last- and :first-child when there is only 1 child, but when I got 2 children, I have a problem. Is there some sort of selector, that only applies, when there are more children than n?

Comment: You mean you want a style to apply to _all_ children, but _only_ if there are more than 3 children? No, you'll need Javascript for that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `:nth-child(n+3)` selector (where 3 is the *n*th minimum child).

```
:last-child:nth-child(n+3) {
     /* Selects the last child which is at least the third child */
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vCZ9A/

Comment: Bear in mind that browser support for these pseudo-selectors is not fantastic.

Comment: @JezenThomas OP already use css3 property. Which means he is not interested in IE

Comment: @sandeep We don't know what he's interested in. Just because he's making something work with CSS3, doesn't mean he's considered browser support.

Comment: Thanks man, that was exactly what I was looking for, no idea why I didn't think of it!

@JezenThomas & sandeep:
Sorry, I didn't clarify this, I want to use this as a userstyle for the Firefox-only extension Stylish. It is for personal use, so I (luckily) don't have to check for browser support.